# Android Google place picker

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

I am using google place picker in my app and each and everything is working fine. But there are some requirements of my app too.

When we open the place picker via intent it just look like this

[image: Place picker]

As you can see there is a search field on the top of Place picker , I just want to change the hint from the search to the string that I want. let say locate or anything else.

Please tell me how can I do this . I am pretty sure it can be done. But from intent builder it seems impossible.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid currently this is not possible to set custom placeholder text in search element. I can see the following feature requests in Google issue tracker you might be interested in:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64892097

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62256415

Feel free to star these feature requests to add your vote and subscribe to notifications.